# Using curl with Meteor API in rocket chat results in an error

Tags: javascript, api, meteor, rocket.chat

Trying to curl [Ombi API](https://demo.ombi.io/swagger/index.html) in Rocket.Chat Webhook script using [Meteor API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html). This is my script:

```js
class Script {
  prepare_outgoing_request({ request }) {
    console.log("SENDING POST");
    var text = request.data.text;
    text = text.substr(7);
    console.log("Input: " + text);
    var text = text.replace(" ", "%20");

    try {
      var url = 'https://ombi.domain.tlc/api/v1/Request/movie/search/' + text;
      console.log(url);
      const result = HTTP.call('GET', url, { 
        headers: { 
          accept: 'application/json',
          ApiKey: 'xxx6d613f69xxx'
        }
      });

      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      console.log(result.content);
      console.log("POST SENT");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('#### ERROR');
    }

    return false;
  };
}
```

And the HTTP response I get in `result` is JSON object `{"error":{}}`.

Where am I going wrong here? If I curl in my Macbook terminal:

```
curl -X GET "https://ombi.domain.tlc/api/v1/Request/movie/search/lord" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "ApiKey: xxx6d613f69xxx"
```

I get back the expected JSON result.

Comment: Looks right to me. And I assume you've already checked that `text` is `lord` in your test? The result looks really wrong though. It should contain statusCode, data, content, and headers (not error). I assume you are running this on the server, right?

Comment: Yes I've checked the text. Yes I'm running on Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS. Is there anything else I can test that might help me?

Comment: Just to confirm: By server I meant on the server-side of your meteor app, as opposed to on the client (browser). Can you confirm that? On the browser this won't work because there is no synchronous execution there.

Comment: I think the code is executed on the server and not on the client side! The app is rocket chat and they support both synchronous and asynchronous executions so I believe it's serverside.

Comment: Just to be sure, I would add a `console.log(Meteor.isClient)` before the HTTP call. The other possibility is that this is run outside of a fiber. You can add a callback to the `HTTP.call` and see whether you get a different result there.

Comment: I get an error when using `console.log(Meteor.isClient)` before the HTTP call.
`Error: ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined at Promise.catch (evalmachine.<anonymous>:11:33) at /snap/rocketchat-server/1427/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40`

Comment: OK, well then we are in a different neck of the woods then we thought. Can you please post your directory structure? a `find . | grep -v node_modules | grep -v .meteor` in your project root would do. And then tell us where the code you show lives in that.

Comment: I don’t really understand. I’ve run the command and I get a lot of directories. What is it you want to know?

Comment: If `Meteor` is not defined, then you are executing this code somewhere there `HTTP` will almost certainly not behave as expected either.

Comment: So I want to know where in your directory structure the above code lives, and ideally how it is called. Which is to say: we need more context.